# how facebook created push notification when its web app is closed

Tags: javascript, html

Recenlty I've notice that I get push notifications from facebook even that I don't have facebook app open. How is that possible?

Comment: Obviously it is not possible. You have to have some app running in the background.

Comment: You have opened facebook in Chrome (or some other) browser and enabled its notificatons. Its from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) which builds off the [ServiceWorker API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/) which allows web applications to register long-lived background services that outlive a specific website visit. As to how this is implemented, even if the browser/website is not in the foreground, there is an application running in the background or there is a handler registered to start/resume the background application when an event is received. Android [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) enable this under-the-hood.

Answer (score 0):

I think Using push notifications...In mobile computing is that the technology doesn't require specific applications on a mobile device to be open in order for a message to be received. This allows a smartphone to receive and display social media  or text message alerts even when the device's screen is locked and the social media application that is pushing the notification is closed.

Comment: I dindn't ask about mobile but about web app.